# How to make a Hidden Tor Bitcoin Mixing Service?

Tags: services, server, tor, mixing

Bitcoiners. I have been trying to seek out a *legit* Bitcoin Mixing service, and I just don't feel secure by putting my coins in their hands. I have scoured the internet trying to find a tutorial on how to make a .onion Mixing Service. I want to be able to help others and me become safer with transactions, and I am running out of luck. If you know how to make a Mixing Service, please let me know how, or give me a link. Also, I would like to be able to have a small transaction fee [E.G. Base Fee of: 0.75%; For every transaction/day an additional 0.002 BTC is taken]. I am really feeling annoyed that I can't find an answer ANYWHERE, so please reply to me ASAP with an answer on how to host a service.

P.S. I am using a Windows XP [Dell Desktop] and Windows Vista [Toshiba Satellite] to host it on. If you have something I ABSOLUTELY NEED to download for the service, you can send it to adaptornode@tormail.org

Comment: BitcoinFog is popular and has been around for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

BitcoinFog is popular and has been around for a few years. If you really want to make your own, you'd need a dedicated server, Tor (for the hidden service), web server software like Apache, and Bitcoin-Qt (or some other bitcoin software which can be interfaced with through PHP). To have it be really safe, you'd need to set in place other precautions like a firewall or a separate server running Bitcoin-Qt.